# How to properly retrieve num_rows | Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there a better way of retrieving the number of rows from a table? Currently I have this which is also returning an error if there are no results:

Error:
    A PHP Error was encountered

```
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: Home::$count</p>
<p>Filename: core/Model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 51</p>

</div>{"status":"ok","content":""}
```

Controller

```
 public function do_messages()
    {
            $this->load->model('message_model');
            $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
            $this->message_model->unread_msg($user_id);
            $mess = $this->message_model->unread_msg_count();
                    if(isset($mess)){
                            $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $mess);
                            echo json_encode($result);
                            exit();
                    }else{
                            $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => '');
                            echo json_encode($result);
                            exit();
                    }
    }
```

Model:

```
function unread_msg($user_id)
    {
            $query_str = "SELECT id FROM messages WHERE view = 0 AND dest = ?";
            $query = $this->db->query($query_str, $user_id);

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                    $this->count = $query->num_rows();
            }
    }
    function unread_msg_count()
    {
    return $this->count;
    }
```

js file:

```
function get_messages()
     {
         $.post(base_url + "index.php/home/do_messages", { user_id : user_msg }, function(data) {
         if (data.status == 'ok')
         {
         $(".new_msg").removeClass('hide').html(data.content);
         }
         else
         {
         }
     }, "json");
            }
    get_messages();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function do_messages()
    {
            $this->load->model('message_model');
            $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
            $this->message_model->unread_msg($user_id);
            $mess = $this->message_model->unread_msg_count();
                    if($mess != false){
                            $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $mess);
                            echo json_encode($result);
                            exit();
                    }else{
                            $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => '');
                            echo json_encode($result);
                            exit();
                    }
    }
```

Model:

```
function unread_msg($user_id)
    {
            $query_str = "SELECT id FROM messages WHERE view = 0 AND dest = ?";
            $query = $this->db->query($query_str, $user_id);

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                    return $query->num_rows();
            } else {
                    return false;
            }
    }
    function unread_msg_count()
    {
    return $this->count;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to make minor changes but the `return $query->num_rows()` and the `return false` set me in the right direction.

Comment: I have all of my models either return my db results, or false. Then in my controllers I always use that check.

Comment: couple of points, mostly style related. why not simply remove the if/else and do $this->count = $query->num_rows().  in the $this->db->query, i prefer to put the second parameter in array even if it is the only one.

Comment: How would you pass $this->count from model to controller? isn't $this->count in the scope of the model only?

Comment: in the OPs code, the $this->count is set in model and returned from get_message_count